# using while(! infile.eof()) Curious how to break it before eof() in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, eof

I am going through a file looking for specific words

`Char[50]=getline(file,/n)`

using getline to store each line into an char array to compare to the string(s) I am looking for

```
If( “<”x “>”==char[50]) || (“<” y “<”==char[50])||(“<”z“>”==char[50])
    Break;
```

Will using `break`, break me out of the loop early?

Comment: FYI [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Either this isn't C++ code, or something went extremely wrong when you tried to paste code in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the b needs to be lowercase.

```
break;
```

Will get you out.